# will askUbuntu go away after 14.10 expires?

Tags: discussion

Will Ask Ubuntu go away after 14.10 expires? I know support for Ubuntu 14.10 stops and the Q&A site won't take any more questions on 14.10

Will all these answers here become unavailable?

Comment: AFAIK the knowledge accumulated here is persistent, and it will last forever and even after.

Answer (score 3):

Of course not; when 14.10 is no longer supported, there'll be support for 15.04, 15.10, 16.04, etc. -- and of course most answers applicable to 14.04 LTS will still work for 14.10, and 14.04 is supported until at least 2019.

Comment: 12.04 and 14.04 both supported until 2017? Only 12.04, i think 14.04 is 2021.

Comment: Corrected the end date for 14.04 support.  LTS is five years from release (paid support may be available longer).

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't. Ask Ubuntu will continue, with support for 15.04, 15.10, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.10 expires soon, but Ubuntu 14.04 is supported until 2019. Also Ubuntu 15.04 is coming out in April 2015.

Every 2 years  new LTS version comes out. LTS versions are supported 5 years.

Comment: Correct. Just correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no currently defined end of Ubuntu (new versions are planned to be released and no mention of this regular cadence of releases stopping).
How long Ask Ubuntu lasts depends on 3 factors:

1. How long Canonical allow us to.
2. How long Stack Exhange allows us to.
3. How long we continue as a community.

The actual information we post to Ask Ubuntu is under a [Creative Commons licence](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), can be freely copied (with attribution), which in the event of any combination of the above 3 points will allow someone to preserve the information elsewhere and even setup an alternative to askUbuntu.